# WCF Error - No endpoint listening

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using WCF to send messages back and forth between a windows service (client) and a winforms app (service host).  Until recently this has worked. Now, when the client attempts to communicate I receive the following error message:

"There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action."

I have spent an entire day on this forum referencing similar issues but have not been able to resolve, hoping if I provide the specifics from my project the answer will jump out at someone.

Here's the code snippet (client side) where the error occurs:

```
var pingHost = new ColumbineWCFServiceReference.ColumbineWCFServiceClient();
pingHost.Open();
if (pingHost.AreYouThere() == true) return true; //<-- this is the line where the "no endpoint listening" error occurs
```

Client side app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IColumbineWCFService" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService/ColumbineWCFService"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IColumbineWCFService"
          contract="IColumbineWCFService" name="WSHttpBinding_IColumbineWCFService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="Nathan-PC\Nathan" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

C# code on the host side:

```
ServiceHost selfHost = null;
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService");
selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ColumbineWCFService), baseAddress);
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IColumbineWCFService), new WSHttpBinding(), "ColumbineWCFService");

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
selfHost.Open();
```

Please note, all code compiles and the service does run as evidenced by the "You have created a service" page that results when the base address is typed into a web browser. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Could you share the entire columbineWCFServiceClient code, instead of just that small part? I think something is wrong with the AreYouThere() method definition. Also, have you tried using a WCF test client to contact the method? Visual Studio has a client you can use to contact it.

Comment: Not sure if that explains it, but there seems to be a discrepancy between `http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService/ColumbineWCFService` in your client's app.config and `http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService` in your host.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.config in the client endpoint configuration:

1. It looks like your endpoint address does not specify the .svc file that is hosting the code for the endpoint. Assuming your .svc file name is ColumbineWCFService.svc your address value would be

   `http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService/ColumbineWCFService.svc`
2. Your contract does not specify your namespace. Assuming your namespace is "ColumbineWCFService" your contract would be "ColumbineWCFService.IColumnbineWCFService"
3. There is no binding configuration named "WSHttpBinding_IColumbineWCFService" though that parameter shouldn't make a difference in whether the endpoint is listening or not.

That said, try the following for your app.config:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ColumbineWCFService/ColumbineWCFService.svc"
binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IColumbineWCFService"
contract="ColumbineWCFService.IColumbineWCFService" name="WSHttpBinding_IColumbineWCFService">
```

If that doesn't work, come back let us know if you have a web.config for your WCF service and post it.